# What's the best Windows archive tool (WinRAR, WinZip, etc)?

Tags: file-compression, zip, rar

I have some data that has been downloaded with the extension `.zip` or `.gz`. I always have had **[WinRAR software](http://www.win-rar.com/start.html?&L=0)** installed on my computer and I was always able to uncompress such files.

But last night I tried to uncompress some zip files but despite the fact that I know the files are healthy, I always get the errors `unable to uncompress all the content` and `file is corrupted`.

So I started searching to find the reason and I understood there is another software named **[WinZip](http://www.winzip.de/index.htm)**.

Now my question is which archive tool should be installed on ones computer generally?

Comment: This site is about recommending software – not about solving issues you have with it.

Answer (score 5):

Use 7-zip.

There are many archive and compression formats and tools that mostly do the same thing. 7zip just happens to support the most formats and features. For details and other options see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_archivers